# How does one continuously draw straight lines in Grease Pencil 2.8?

Tags: grease-pencil

When I select the Line option in the Shapes pull-down menu inside Grease Pencil 2.8 I can only draw one line at a time at the moment.[image]

Answer (score 1):

alt key only works for horizontal and vertical line. I'm still looking for straight line with an angle. Hope it helps you a bit ;)

Press '**W**' to select which path you want to draw (**line**, rectangle or circle)